# React-Native error when starting Android studio Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native, java-8

I am new to App Development and React-native, I am trying to start the Emulator for Android studio using 'npx react-native run-android' in VS Code, No matter what I do I always get the Following error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
15 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 13 up-to-date
Note: C:\Users\User\Testing\android\app\src\debug\java\com\testing\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x247a2315) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x247a2315

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.      

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\User\Testing\android\app\src\debug\java\com\testing\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x247a2315) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x247a2315

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.      

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

    at makeError (C:\Users\User\Testing\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\User\Testing\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\User\Testing\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\User\Testing\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 29
targetSdkVersion = 29
ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
```

I am genuinely stuck at this point any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you have try echo $JAVA_HOME and is it pointing to the right jdk 8 path?

Comment: I did and it was pointing to the correct location, the problem in this case was just the version of the JDK that was installed, which I have fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had the latest version of the JDK (jdk-16.0.1) installed which was causing errors, by downgrading (to jdk-15.0.2) and updating my system variables again that solved the problem for me.